# Azure Media Services restrict content by country not working

Tags: azure-media-services

I'm using Geo-filtering to restrict content delivery by CDN, but its not working. I've configured 2 paths, one for the entire locator and one for a file, but I'm still can reproduce the video. I'm using  Azure CDN Standard from Verizon.

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
| **Path**                            |**Action**  | **Country Codes** | 
------------------------------------------------------------------------
| /{locator_name}/{file.ism/manifest} | Block      |   Mexico, MX      |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
| /{locator_name}                     | Block      |   Mexico, MX      |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I tested that traffic its pointed to the CDN using [www.digwebinterface.com](http://www.digwebinterface.com) too, that its working fine.

Should I use the storage link instead?

Answer (score 0):

To rule out if this is an issue with how you are specifying your path, I would recommend trying this with a path of just "/" which indicates that all requests for the CDN endpoint should be blocked. If this also doesn't work then we would need to know the IP(s) that you aren't seeing as being blocked.

Comment: Hi Anton! Thank you for your answer. We uploaded content in Azure Media Services that must be streamed only in Mexico. I'm not sure if the path that I need to set in Geo-filtering must be the locator path created when we published the asset in Azure Media Services or the path where the asset is in Azure Storage. I tested the path "/" but video is still available. We are based in Mexico, so for tests I'm trying to block the content for my country to ensure we cannot view the content but its not working or maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Anton, looks like after aply the path "/" I was able to view the content due to cache, after clear it, I receive the error "A network error caused the video download to fail part-way. Please check your network connection or try again later. (0x20200259)". I supposed this is fine. Now I need to findout how to restrict just some content and not the entire assets in our account in Azure Media Services.

Comment: You should receive back an HTTP 403 error if geo blocking is working correctly. The client you are using may be masking this HTTP response. To remove the client behavior you can just try requesting the hostname for the streaming endpoint from a browser. No need to specify a specific file, asset, etc. If your IP is being blocked you should see a 403 response in your browser.